# Skia error when trying to retrieve a bitmap downloaded from Google Sign-in

Tags: java, android, google-signin, skia

So, I am downloading the profile picture from the `Google SIgn-in api` and I save it to a hidden file. The problem is that when I try to retrieve it, it throws me: `D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'`. However when I retrieve an image from `FireBaseStorage` and save that one to the hidden file I can retrieve it whithout any problems.

I tried BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(), but then I had a message telling me skia wasn't able to decode the file and it returned null.

The method I use to retrieve the profile picture and call the method that will save the file

```
private void getUsersPic() {
        Bitmap profilePic;

        try {
            InputStream in = new URL(AppData.getUser().getPicture()).openConnection().getInputStream();
            profilePic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

            int size = profilePic.getRowBytes()*profilePic.getHeight();

            ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[size];

            profilePic.copyPixelsToBuffer(b);

            b.position(0);
            b.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

            SaveBitmapToFile.saveBitmap(bytes , AppData.getUser().getName()+AppData.getUser().getLastName());

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Get profile pic: "+e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Save the file

```
public static void saveBitmap(byte[] bitmap, String key) {

        String path = AppData.getAppContext().getFilesDir()+"/.image"+"/";

        File fileDir = new File(path);

        if(!fileDir.isDirectory())
            fileDir.mkdirs();


        try {
            File bitmapDir = new File(fileDir+"/"+key);
            bitmapDir.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(bitmapDir);

            stream.write(bitmap);
            stream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem creating file "+e.toString()+ " Directory: "+fileDir);
        }
    }
```

Retrieve and return a bitmap

```
 public static Bitmap getBitmap(String key) {

        File file = new File(AppData.getAppContext().getFilesDir()+"/.image/"+key);

        try {
            BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);//BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception getting bitmap: "+e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The last method should return a Bitmap and it is doing it. It is just not working when the image comes from the Google Sign-in api.

Comment: tried to verify what bytes are passed to `BitmapFactory#decodeStream` method? if so that are the first 8 bytes ([magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures))?

Comment: I get -64-49-42-1-64-52-40-1, this code is not on the wikipedia page

Comment: you dont need `copyPixelsToBuffer()` - you need `compress()` instead

Comment: Thank you !! Can you write an answer to my question so I can mark it as a solution ?

Comment: write a self-answer then, good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pskink said in the comment of the post, I had to use compress() instead of copyPixelToBuffer(). Here is my updated method:

```
private void getUsersPic() {
        Bitmap profilePic;

        try {
            InputStream in = new URL(AppData.getUser().getPicture()).openConnection().getInputStream();
            profilePic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            profilePic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

            SaveBitmapToFile.saveBitmap(stream.toByteArray() , AppData.getUser().getName()+AppData.getUser().getLastName());

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Get profile pic: "+e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: and do not use that `ByteArrayOutputStream` - use directly `FileOutputStream` instead - simply pass `profilePic` to `SaveBitmapToFile.saveBitmap` method instead of `stream.toByteArray()`

Comment: Well my saveBitmap() methods take a byte array as a parameter